# Can not drag slider handles

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I've created a time range slider (noUiSlider) programmatically.

It's working fine except that, I'm NOT able to drag the slider handles (that is available as a default behaviour), in order to change the slider value(s).

```
var noUiSlider = require('./js/nouislider');

var sliderDiv = document.createElement("div");
sliderDiv.id = "slider-"+soundElement.description;
var sliderElem: any = noUiSlider.create(sliderDiv, {
    start: [0, 50],
    tooltips: [true, true],
    behaviour: "tap-drag",
    connect: true,
    orientation: 'vertical',
    range: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    }
});
soundElementIframe.appendChild(sliderDiv);
```

I've not been able to figure out, why drag interaction is not working (while everything else like 'tap' is working fine). I'd really appreciate any help around this.

[image]

Comment: A. any errors in the `console`? B. Can you create a snippet which reproduce this problem so we could debug it?

Comment: What version are you using? Earlier versions had issues being in iframes.

Comment: @Lg102 I'm using noUiSlider 10.0.0

Comment: I don't have anything on me to test this, but your snippet only appends the slider to the DOM after initializing it. Could you try moving that around?

Comment: Hi @MoshFeu, There are no errors in the console. I'm trying to create the slider control in a new page(with very basic layout). The problem is not reproducible there. Will try and make the ui similar to that of my application so as to reproduce the issue. Will let you know once I'm able to isolate the same.

Comment: Ok then. Because maybe it not related directly to the slider but for other elements on the page, or css or something..

Comment: Better to add fiddle so others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening is that you create your slider, then when you append it, it loses its (default?) listeners. To avoid this, append your div *then* initialize the noUiSlider element.

```js
const sliderDiv = document.createElement('div');
soundElementIframe.appendChild(sliderDiv);
noUiSlider.create(sliderDiv, options);
```

If this still doesn't work, try reselecting the new appended `sliderDiv` element and passing that into the `noUiSlider.create()` method.